# git subtree split into new repo, meanwhile commits to old repo

Tags: git, git-subtree

We are using two long scripts, which move a bunch of files in our repository using `git mv`. Files from `src` are moved into `src/dir1` and `src/src_public/dir2`,where `src/src_public/dir2` is a submodule.
One line in such script would for example look like this:

```
git mv src/file1 src/dir1/; git subtree split -P dir1 -b branch_dir1
```

Then we pull the new order from the old repository into our new one with

```
git pull /path/to/old/repo branch_dir1
```

Now a coworker pushed new commits to the old repository using the old directory structure. I want to migrate those commits the the new repository with the new structure.

That coworker changed files in `src` that are supposed to go in the submodule `dir2`. How do I merge these new commits into the submodule?

Comment: Why not `git subtree push`? See [the docs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/plain/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) and [examples](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec).

Comment: How to know which subtrees to push ?  Have to push every subdirectory of the original repo to catch up on commits?  For an old repo file, src/file1 whose destination should be in the new repo src/src_public/file1, the subtree split man page implies src/file1 will arrive at the new repo root.

Comment: The first part of catching up on commits is finding out about them.  Using, for d in "${dirs[@]}" ; do git log --name-status --since="2018-01-30" -- "$HOME/gitrepos/mtip/$d" > "$HOME/log_$d.txt"

Comment: Knowing that only 4 of >12 directories have new commits, what are the relative merits of doing subtree push from local old repo ?  The destination is not remote, but the new local repo.  How does subtree push differ from re-doing the subtree split in the old repo on these 4 directories and subtree pull from the new repo ?